# No possibility to update model attributes with a block syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

There is a block syntax for new and create that goes like this:

```
 user = User.create do |u|
    u.name = "David"
    u.mail = "dhh@rails.com"
 end
```

Is there a block syntax that would be valid in Rails 3 and Rails 4 for updating attributes? Something like:

```
  user = User.where(name: "David").first

  user.update_attributes do |u|
    u.mail = "dhh@rubyonrails.com"
  end
```

Maybe not `update_attributes` but something similar. I have been searching the web and the Rails 4 source on Github, and i think there isn't such a thing. Am I wrong?

P.S. i'm not looking for making any monkey patch methods or something similar, just interested if there is a method that comes by default with `ActiveRecord`.

Comment: Good idea, but I don't think there exists such a thing in Rails4.

Comment: Na, update_attributes still only accepts a hash so you could create the hash then call update_attributes, there was a pull request to add the feature last month but it was turned down: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/11599

Comment: I mean it may be basically useless, i was just searching for it so i could write it in a prettier manner, cause i have to update many attributes once, and it would be prettier if it was in a block i belive

Comment: You can always indent it like you would indent a block.

Comment: yeah, i'm aware of that also, and it is one of my solutions :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use, [#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) (available since Ruby 1.9) if you want the block syntax:

```
user.tap do |u|
  u.mail = "dhh@rubyonrails.com"
end
user.save
```

One caveat in Rails 3 is it avoids mass assignment protection compared to `#update_attributes`, which may or may not be what you want.  In Rails 4 of course it doesn't matter because attributes are protected differently (using strong parameters).

Comment: Nice solution, thank you! Sorry for waiting for the response!